# Show that $c^2 = d^2 = ab$ in an Argand diagram

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following question.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two points on the unit circle $∣z∣$ $=$ $1$ in the Argand diagram. Let $C$ and $D$ be
> the midpoints of the minor arc and the major arc of AB on the unit circle. Denote by $a, b, c, d$
> the complex numbers representing $A, B, C, D$ respectively.
> The question is to show that $c^2 = d^2 = ab$

---

I am new to complex numbers. I figure out that C and D will be on the same line but this information seems to be useless. Any hint to approach this question? Do i need to convert $A,B,C,D$ into polar form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your intuition is correct to write the numbers in polar form. That way, if

\begin{equation*}
a = e^{i\theta_{a}}\hspace{1pc} \mbox{ and }\hspace{1pc} b = e^{i\theta_{b}},
\end{equation*}

then $c$ and $d$ (on the minor arc and major arc, respectively) are such that

\begin{equation*}
c = e^{i\frac{\theta_{a}+\theta_{b}}{2}}\hspace{1pc} \mbox{ and }\hspace{1pc} d = e^{i\frac{\theta_{a}+\theta_{b}}{2}}e^{i \pi }
\end{equation*}

where I have used that multiplication by $e^{i\pi}$ rotates $c$ by an angle $\pi$ (so you're absolutely correct that $C$ and $D$ are on the same line). Then

\begin{equation*}
c^{2} = e^{i(\theta_{a}+\theta_{b})}\hspace{1pc} \mbox{ and }\hspace{1pc} d^{2} = e^{i(\theta_{a}+\theta_{b})}e^{i 2\pi} = e^{i(\theta_{a}+\theta_{b})}
\end{equation*}

(because $e^{i2\pi} = \cos{(2\pi)} + i\sin{(2\pi)} =1$) and

\begin{equation*}
ab = e^{i(\theta_{a}+\theta_{b})}.
\end{equation*}

This works analogously if $c$ and $d$ are on the major arc and minor arc, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to conduct the proof is to start with a simple specific situation and then generalize it.  Since $ \ C \ $ and $ \ D \ $ are midpoints of the minor and major arcs $ \ \widehat{AB} \ \ $ on the unit circle, then $ \ \overline{CD} \ $ is a diameter of the circle (as you observed) and the perpendicular bisector of the *chord* $ \overline{AB} \ \ . \ $  If we position $ \ \overline{CD} \ $ on the $ \ x-$axis, then $ \ c_0 \ = \ 1 \ $ and $ \ d_0 \ = \ -1 \ \ . \ $  The endpoints of the perpendicular chord $ \ \overline{AB} \ $ are then the complex conjugates $ \ a_0 \ $ and $ \ b_0 \ = \ \overline{a_0} \ \ . \ $  It is then plain that $ \ c_0^2 \ = \ d_0^2 \ = \ a_0b_0 \ = \ a_0 \overline{a_0} \ = \ 1 \ \ . \ $  (This is the "trivial" case.)

If we now position $ \ C \ $ instead so that it is represented by $ \ c \ = \ \alpha \ + \ i·\beta \ \ , \ $ with $ \ c \overline{c} \ = \ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ this has the effect of rotating all of these points on the unit circle by an angle $ \ \theta \ $ given by $ \ \tan \theta \ = \ \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \ \ $ (with appropriate quadrant adjustments).  We then have $ \ d \ = \ (-1)·(\alpha \ + \ i·\beta) \ \ , \ \ a \ = \ a_0·(\alpha \ + \ i·\beta) \ \ $ and $ \ b \ = \ \overline{a_0}·(\alpha \ + \ i·\beta) \ \ . \ $  The equation becomes
$$ c^2 \ = \ (\alpha \ + \ i·\beta)^2 \ \  = \ \ (-1)^2·(\alpha \ + \ i·\beta)^2 \ \ = \ \ d^2 \ \  $$

$$  = \ a_0·(\alpha \ + \ i·\beta)·\overline{a_0}·(\alpha \ + \ i·\beta) \ \ = \ \ ab \ \ = \ \ a\overline{a_0}·(\alpha \ + \ i·\beta)^2  = \ \ (\alpha \ + \ i·\beta)^2 \ \ .  $$
[Since $ \ c \ = \ e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta} \ \ , \ $ we can also write this in the more succinct form
$$ c^2 \ \ = \ \ ( \ e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta} \ )^2 \ \ = \ \ e^{ \ i \ · \ 2 \theta} \ \ = \ \ ( \ -e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta} \ )^2 \ \ = \ \ d^2 $$
$$  = \ a_0·e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta}·\overline{a_0}·e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta} \ \ = \ \ ab \ \ = \ \ a\overline{a_0}·(e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta})^2  = \ \ e^{ \ i \ · \ 2 \theta} \ \ ,  $$
akin to **kandb**'s argument.

(We may also write $ \ d \ = \ e^{ \ i \ · \ [\theta + \pi]} \ \Rightarrow \ d^2 \ = \ e^{ \ i \ · \ 2·[\theta + \pi]} \ = \ e^{ \ i \ · \  [2 \theta + 2 \pi]} \ = \ e^{ \ i \ · \   2\theta  }·e^{ \ i \ · \   2\pi } \ = \ e^{ \ i \ · \   2\theta  } \ · \ 1 \ \ . ) \ ]  $

You are right that one definitely wants to make use of polar form and the concept of complex multiplication as rotation in the Argand plane in some way: a general argument writing $ \ a \ , \ b \ , \ $ and $ \ c \ $ entirely in "Cartesian form" is *spectacularly* tedious.